# Cannot install macOS Mojave on external spinning drive. Error: This Mac can only install macOS on APFS-formatted drives

Tags: macos, mac, disk-utility, mojave, external-disk

I am using the `Install macOS Mojave.app` installer on my Mac mini (2018) running [Mojave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS_Mojave) 10.14.5 to install Mojave on a formatted external [spinning disk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_disk_drive) laptop drive (a Toshiba model with case).

I successfully formatted the drive using [Disk Utility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_Utility) app in the [GUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table) format.

Now when running the Mojave installer, it refuses to install on the external drive saying:

> This Mac can only install macOS on APFS-formatted drives.

But I thought [APFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_File_System) was intended only for [solid-state drives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid-state_drive), not spinning drives. And there was no APFS option in Disk Utility that I could see.

➥ Is it now impossible to install and boot on an external spinning drive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there. Check again in *Disk Utility* app.

## *Format*

You will find APFS as an option in the `Format` pop-up menu.

## *Scheme*

You make the same choice of GUID Partition in the other pop-up menu `Scheme`.

[image: screenshot of Disk Utility > Erase > Format > APFS.]